# "list" the counter is greater than the number of elements within the

Tags: android, list

Problem with "list" the counter is greater than the number of elements within the

This is filled by the response of a server.

public class ListQuestions extends Activity{

```
private ListQuestionsAdapter adapter;
ListView listquestion;
List<ResponseQuestionDto> questions = new ArrayList<>();
List<ResponseQuestionDto> questionsSelected;
int positionQuestion;
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    try{

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listquestions);

        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "",
                getString(R.string.progress), true);

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                questions = BusinessLogic.getQuestions(LiveCookie.getInstance().getToken());

                mHandler.post(mUpdate);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Util.alert(ListQuestions.this, getString(R.string.Error));
            }
        }

    };
    thread.start();



    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(ListQuestions.this, getString(R.string.Error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}

final Runnable mUpdate = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            dialog.dismiss();

            questionsSelected = LiveCookie.getInstance().getQuestionsSelected();
            positionQuestion = LiveCookie.getInstance().getPositionQuestion();

            try {

                if(questionsSelected != null)
                {
                    for (int i=0;i<questionsSelected.size();i++) {
                        if (questionsSelected != null) {
                            if (questionsSelected.get(i).pregunta != null) {
                                if (positionQuestion != i) {
                                    for (int e = 0; e < questions.size(); e++) {
                                        if (questions.get(e) != null) {
                                            if (questions.get(e).pregunta.equals(questionsSelected.get(i).pregunta)) {
                                                questions.remove(questions.get(e));
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Not Used
            }

            listquestion = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listquestion);

            adapter = new ListQuestionsAdapter(ListQuestions.this,questions);
            listquestion.setAdapter(adapter);

            listquestion.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter2, View v, int position, long id) {

                    questionsSelected = LiveCookie.getInstance().getQuestionsSelected();

                    ResponseQuestionDto selected = questions.get(position);

                    positionQuestion = LiveCookie.getInstance().getPositionQuestion();

                    questionsSelected.set(positionQuestion,selected);

                    LiveCookie.getInstance().setQuestionsSelected(questionsSelected);

                    ListQuestions.this.finish();

                }});

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(ListQuestions.this, getString(R.string.Error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ListQuestions.this.finish();

        }
    }
};
```

}

At first the list is 14 but when I check it in the "setOnItemClickListener" this is 18.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l57J.png)

Comment: How do you fill this list?

Comment: check the question again please @KillerDeath

Answer (score 0):

you have to put all code, and where is the code affect the problem?

as well you check before getting data from the list to avoid this problem

```
if(counter<=list.size-1){
//put your code
}
```

Comment: @juliandavid ok, which line cause the problem?

Comment: in this line "questions = BusinessLogic.getQuestions(LiveCookie.getInstance().getToken());" de array is 15 but in this is de problem: "ResponseQuestionDto selected = questions.get(position);"